# How to retrieve the attribute for a class

Tags: jquery

I have got a HTML as shown below

```
<div id="activeui4" class="activateUiHTML" data-role="collapsible">
    <div class="Topping-and-Crusting-section">
        <a style="display:block" id="4" vendor_items_id="4" class="btn  btn-sm topp  btn-sm-active" data-count="1">topping  <span>1</span></a> 
        <a style="display:block" id="4" vendor_items_id="4" class="btn  btn-sm crust " data-count="0"> crust  <span></span></a>                
    </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to retrieve the value `data-count` of class `btn  btn-sm topp  btn-sm-active`

I tried it like this:

```
var count = $(".activateUiHTML div#"+id_attr_val+".Topping-and-Crusting-section").find(".top").attr('data-count');
alert(count);
```

But I get back `undefined`.

Answer (score 3):

```
var count = $(".activateUiHTML .Topping-and-Crusting-section").find(".topp").data('count');
alert(count);
```

Your class selector **'top'** is misspelled.

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/j0bo063s/

Comment: Thanks a lot . I was in a hurry . :)

Comment: you should use `data()` function to reduce scalability issue. `$(".activateUiHTML .Topping-and-Crusting-section").find(".topp").data('count');`

Answer (score 1):

You miss spelled the class find('.top') theres no such element instead use .find('.topp')

use data function of jquery

```
var count = $(".activateUiHTML div#"+id_attr_val+".Topping-and-Crusting-section").find(".top").data('count');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code:

```
var count = $("#activeui4 a.btn-sm-active").attr('data-count');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here your problem in this line

```
class="btn  btn-sm topp  btn-sm-active"
```

in your javascript you called it as `.top` but in your html you have `.topp`

```
.find(".top")
```

Answer (score 0):

Cause :
  you are using wrong selector. class name is "topp" rather then "top".

so resolution is to change class name

```
var count = $(".activateUiHTML div#"+id_attr_val+".Topping-and-Crusting-section").find(".topp").data('count');
```

Future problem:
there are 2 anchors with same class "top" so it will return data count from first element it 
found. so be specific . either use id or some specific class in "div"